# SonarQube 5.6 using Jazz RTC plugin 1.1 missing blame information

Tags: sonarqube, rtc, blame, ibm-jazz

When running the SonarQube 5.6 using Jazz RTC plugin 1.1 in a maven build to get blame information from an RTC project I am hitting the following and no blame information is being collected:

```
[INFO] 11:46:26.782 Sensor SCM Sensor (wrapped)
[INFO] 11:46:26.782 SCM provider for this project is: jazz
[INFO] 11:46:26.782 1 files to be analyzed
[DEBUG] 11:46:26.797 Working directory: B:\Source
[DEBUG] 11:46:26.797 Executing: cmd /C call lscm annotate -u ***** -P ******** pom.xml
[DEBUG] 11:46:26.813 Skipping untracked file: pom.xml. Annotate command exit code: 1
[INFO] 11:46:26.813 0/1 files analyzed
[WARNING] 11:46:26.813 Missing blame information for the following files:
[WARNING] 11:46:26.813   * B:/Source/pom.xml
[WARNING] 11:46:26.813 This may lead to missing/broken features in SonarQube
[INFO] 11:46:26.813 Sensor SCM Sensor (wrapped) (done) | time=31ms
```

Please advise how to resolve

Comment: Is `/Source/pom.xml` under version control?

Comment: Yes /Source/pom.xml is under version control

Comment: What happens, if you execute `lscm annotate -u ***** -P ******** pom.xml` in the command line (in the directory `B:\Source`, when replacing `*`s with the correct username and password)?

Comment: Running the following command works:
cd B:\Source 
lscm annotate -u ***** -P ******** pom.xml

Also running the following in the same command window returns Exit Code is 0

echo Exit Code is %errorlevel%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed in SonarQube version 5.6.7